# Laravel View Composer not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I've created the following View Composer:

Http\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer(
            'layouts.cart',
            'App\Http\ViewComposers\CartComposer'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Http\ViewComposers\CartComposer

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Iluminate\View\View;
use App\Order;

class CartComposer
{
    public cartDetails = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //dd('here1');
        $orderToken = session('o_token');
        $this->cartDetails = Order::getOrderDetails($orderToken);
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        //dd('here2');
        $view->with('cart', ['total_items' => 7]);
    }
}
```

Just for the sake of testing, I'm returning a hardcoded array ['total_items' => 7]

And now my view which is included via @include in my header.blade.php:

views\layouts\cart.blade.php

```
<div class="cart-menu">
  <i class="black large cart icon"></i>
  @if (/*isset($cart->total_items) &&*/ $cart->total_items > 0)
  <div class="floating ui red label cart-items-badge">{{ $cart->total_items }}</div>
  @endif
</div>
```

I've registered it by  adding it to the providers array:

> App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,

When I access my page I'm getting a 'Page is Not Responding' error. I can't even see the Laravel error.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Check your error logs? Look in both `/storage/logs` and where your webserver logs are located.

Comment: @aynber Indeed, looking at /storage/logs helped me to find out the issue. Thanks for the suggestion. Is there a way to 'activate' error logs on screen?

Answer (score 2):

Use this ComposerServiceProvider file

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer(
            'layouts.cart',
            'App\Http\ViewComposers\CartComposer'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

views\layouts\cart.blade.php use $cart['total_items'] instead of $cart->total_items

```
<div class="cart-menu">
  <i class="black large cart icon"></i>
  @if ($cart['total_items'] > 0)
  <div class="floating ui red label cart-items-badge">{{ $cart['total_items'] }}</div>
  @endif
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, I'm still getting the same error. By the way, I don't see any difference between your service provider and mine. You're using the View facade while I'm using the helper, which I don't think makes a difference, am I wrong?